# Loading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, load, loading

I have a Javascript function that looks like this ...

```
function loadInventory() {
  var json = [<?php echo $_SESSION['inventory']; ?>];

  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    for(var key in obj.rgDescriptions) {
      document.getElementById('userInventory').innerHTML += '<div class="col-sm-4"><div style="background-color: #2e2e2e;">'+obj.rgDescriptions[key].market_hash_name+'</div></div>';
      document.getElementById('loader').classList.remove('loader');
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, it will take a couple of seconds for this function to be completed, which isn't a problem.

However, I want to load the page fully before running that function as the page has a loading animation which is removed in `loadInventory()` once the HTML has been added.

I've tried doing this ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    loadInventory();
  });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work very well. The function runs before the page is loaded fully so you can't see the loading animation.

**CONCLUSION:**

I want to load the page fully. Once that is done, then I want to run `loadInventory()` which will add more HTML to the page.

Sorry for the mess, it's very difficult to explain really!

Comment: Wait... what is this line doing? `var json = [<?php echo $_SESSION['inventory']; ?>];`

Comment: It's a really bad way of storing the JSON. :P

Comment: It just throws `unexpected token` error in my console. How does that even work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` to defer running the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(loadInventory, 1);
});
```

Since `setTimeout` runs the function asynchronously through the event loop, it won't be called until all the synchronous actions of loading the page are completed.

Comment: That will just run the function once per millisecond, wouldn't it? Not really what I am trying to do.

Comment: I meant `setTimeout`, I fixed it.

Comment: It is worth noting that the function will run as soon as the call stack is empty and at least one millisecond elapsed since the call of the `setTimeout` function. That's why `setTimeout` was used here (I suppose).

Comment: This seems to work decently. However, is it a safe way of doing it though?

Comment: The browser won't be responsive while it's doing its thing. There's not really an easy way to solve that.

Comment: @Barmar There is a reasonably easy way of solving it. You could `setInterval` to 0 ms for a function that would be the inside of the `for` loop (plus increment of i). Thus, the inside of the loop would be called every time the stack would be empty, and it would allow other actions on the page.

Comment: Yes, you could use `setInterval` and do each array element in a different iteration of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried removing the `$(window).load` part?  `.load` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Comment: That will run the function before the page has loaded fully, meaning that I can't see the loading animation.

Comment: Where are you placing the code?  If you put it at the bottom of the page rather than the top, just before </body>, does it execute as you want it to?